# How does ng-repeat rendering work under the hood?

Tags: angularjs, dom

I am an Angularjs rookie. Recently I am reading guide in Angularjs website and get some confusion.

In angularjs API Document about `ngRepeat`, it says:

> If you are working with objects that have an identifier property, you should track by the identifier instead of the whole object. Should you reload your data later, ngRepeat will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones. For large collections, this significantly improves rendering performance. If you don't have a unique identifier, track by $index can also provide a performance boost.

I don't understand this content:

> Should you reload your data later, ngRepeat will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones.

What this sentence mean? Can you give me an example?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ngRepeat` behavior changes with and without `track by`.

When the collection changes:

**Without `track by`:**

Angular rebuild the DOM (destroy and create again each DOM element).

**With `track by`:**

Angular retrieve the DOM element of each item and update the values.

As the doc said:

> For large collections, this significantly improves rendering performance.

That behavior is really well explained in [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Say you have ng-repeat build two elements like this:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Then you add three more elements to the object to get this:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

The point is, the first two divs won't be removed from the DOM and then recreated and reinserted, but only the three new ones will be added.

The same goes when if the first two elements of your objects were changed, but the element they're being tracked by remains the same (thus they recommend $index) - the two DOM elements (the divs) would still be intact, just their contents replaced.

Of course, no content in the mini-example I gave you, but you get the point. Think of a `track by` variable as a "glue" that keeps DOM in place.